# Serial Port Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I am trying to open a port in order to communicate with a barcode scanner , but all I get is a

> System.IO.IOException a device attached to the system is not functioning.

This abnormal because I have tested the device using a COM Port monitor. And by testing I mean I read some barcodes with the scanner I watched the input. Everything was working just fine... This is my simple code:

```
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM10");            
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Port opened");
```

---

**Note:** I have already checked out almost every suggested solution on the forum but nothing solved my problem... Also, using the Process Manager I checked and made sure that the COM Port is not used by any other application!

Comment: When you used the Port Monitor, was it using the same port; baud; and flow control?  I notice you are using `DTR` and `RTS` and yet `Handshake = Handshake.None`.  That could be a problem

Comment: Yes I am using exactly the same settings as the port monitor. I also set the RTS and DTR to false... Nothing changed...

Comment: It would be better to check the details of where and what is the problem with VisualStudio debugging execution or with a tool such as [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-risk-detection/concepts/application-verifier).

Answer (score 0):

Try to short your code to remove defaults like this:

```
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM10");            
    _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
    _serialPort.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Port opened");
```

Comment: Try another Port